# How to get a public key from ECDsa in C#

Tags: c#, public-key-encryption, ecdsa

In C# I can create an `RSA` public/private key pair...

```cs
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();

byte[] priKey = rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey();
byte[] pubKey = rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey();
```

Now I want to do *effectively* the same thing using `ECDsa`...

```cs
ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();

byte[] priKey = ecdsa.ExportECPrivateKey();
...
```

...but I can't seem to find a method allowing the public key to be exported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`

```cs
var publicKey = ecdsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
```

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.exportsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_AsymmetricAlgorithm_ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo) say:

> Exports the public-key portion of the current key in the X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo format

Found about "SubjectPublicKeyInfo" [source](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Subject%20Public%20Key%20Info%5D)

> The Subject Public Key Info (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) field carries the Public Key component of its associated subject, as well as an indication of the algorithm, and any algorithm parameters, with which the public component is to be used.

PS: there is also a [`TryExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.tryexportsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-5.0)